# Seed() Output progress to Package Manager Console

Tags: c#, nuget, poco

In the Seed() method for my POCO migration, I'm trying to output a message to the Package Manager Console, I've tried the following with no luck.

```
protected override void Seed(DBContext context)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Test Message");
    Debug.WriteLine("Test Message");
}
```

Using the *-Verbose* command doesn't make any difference to the output.

Any ideas on how to proceed?

Comment: Not sure if you need to specify `-verbose` or similar?

Comment: It's kludgy, but I know it will print exception messages